# Connecting Visual Studio Code (VSCode) to VirtualBox VM

Tags: ssh, visual-studio-code, virtual-machine, virtualbox

I've been using WSL to debug C in VSCode, using Ubuntu from the Windows Store.

However, because my school projects must be able to run on a provided Virtual Machine (Lubuntu, in this case), it would be of great help if I could debug my code on Windows, through a connection to the Virtual Machine.

I've failed to find any good tutorials on this, so I tried playing around with the `ip addr show` command and connecting to the resulting address using ssh, but to no avail.

What would be the best approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Found the solution. In the VM settings, I needed to add a Network Host-only Adapter. From there, I installed `openssh-server` in my VM:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server openssh-client
```

Then, by calling `ifconfig` I got my VM's ip (`enp0s8` interface) and connected to it via ssh.

Hopefully this helps anyone facing the same issue.

Comment: In case anyone stumbles upon this: You need to call `ifconfig` *inside* the VM, which gave me the correct IP `192.168.56.101` which I can use as argument to my ssh client. 
Windows task manager lists the host-only vbox adapter under IP `192.168.56.1`, which is *not* the one you need.